# How can I return an initialized dialog object from function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to learn OO Javascript so I can write some cleaner code. In my code below I am using the JQuery UI Dialog object and my own class so I can easily initialize lots of Dialogs.

The problem is the function is not returning the dialog object, so I can't access the method and properties from it.

```
  /*
*  Load AddTaskForm dialog
*/
$('#AddTask').click(function ()
{
    /* Ajax request to load form into it */
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: '/Planner/Planner/LoadAddTaskForm',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (AddTaskForm)
        {
            var d = new AddDialog();
            var result = d.Dialog();

              /* AddTaskDialog.html(AddTaskForm);
            AddTaskDialog.dialog('open');*/
        }
    });
});



function AddDialog()
{
    this.Dialog = function()
    {
        $('<div></div>').dialog(
        {
            width: 580,
            height: 410,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Basic Dialog',
            buttons:
                {
                    Cancel: function ()
                    {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    'Create Task': function ()
                    {

                    }
                },
                close: function ()
                {
                    $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                }
        });
    } 
}
```

** Updated Code

```
  /*
*  Load AddTaskForm dialog
*/
$('#AddTask').click(function ()
{
    /* Ajax request to load form into it */
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: '/Planner/Planner/LoadAddTaskForm',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (AddTaskForm)
        {
            var AddTaskDialog = $('<div></div>');
            AddTaskDialog.dialog(AddTaskDialogOptions);
            AddTaskDialog.html(AddTaskForm);
            AddTaskDialog.dialog('open');
        }
    });
});


/*
*  Add task dialog default options
*/
var AddTaskDialogOptions = {
    width: 580,
    height: 410,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'Basic Dialog',
    buttons:
        {
            Cancel: function ()
            {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            'Create Task': function ()
            {

            }
        },
    close: function ()
    {
        $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
    }
}
```

This works

```
 /*
*  Load AddTaskForm dialog
*/
$('#AddTask').click(function ()
{
    var addTaskDialog = $('<div></div>');
    addTaskDialog.dialog(AddTaskDialogOptions);
    addTaskDialog.html('wowowo');
    addTaskDialog.dialog('open');  
});
```

This does not work

```
 /* Ajax request to load form into it */
    $.ajax({
        type: 'Get',
        url: '/Planner/Planner/LoadAddTaskForm',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (AddTaskForm)
        {
            var addTaskDialog = $('<div></div>');
            addTaskDialog.dialog(AddTaskDialogOptions);
            addTaskDialog.html(AddTaskForm);
            addTaskDialog.dialog('open');  
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That´s because you dont "return" any dialog, but a function...

And btw this kind of coding is everything, but not clean!
The dialog is already a class, it is already a object. Same like jQuery. You don´t need to wrap it into a function, then into another class.

jQuery ui dialog is a jquery ui widget. that means, that you can easily access this using `$("something").dialog("widget")` and you get the instance of the dialog.

if you want it anonymous but accessable you should do this.

```
var myDialogMarkup = $("<div></div>").dialog();
```

and when you want it back, you do `myDialogMarkup.dialog("widget")` or `myDialog.dialog("methodtodo")`

and if you want to do always the same dialog, just do this

```
var myDialogDefaultVars = {
            width: 580,
            height: 410,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Basic Dialog',
            buttons:
                {
                    Cancel: function ()
                    {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },
                    'Create Task': function ()
                    {

                    }
                },
                close: function ()
                {
                    $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                }
        }
```

and then

```
$("<div></div>").dialog(myDialogDefaultVars);
```

**Update**

If you insist to do it your style

```
function AddDialog()
{
    this.Dialog = function()
    {
         return $('<div></div>').dialog(
        { ... });
    }
}
```

just "return" it :)

or if you want to just return the component

```
function AddDialog()
{
    this.Dialog = function()
    {
         return $('<div></div>').dialog(
        { ... }).dialog("widget");
    }
}
```

the dialog("widget") will give you the widget-component.
Then you could do

```
var d = new AddDialog();
d.Dialog().close();
```

Comment: Good points Luke. Just out of curiosity how would I return a dialog object instead of a function?

Comment: Thanks for providing that. Just one more thing. With your first example I get an "Object doesn't support this property or method" when I try to close or cancel the form. It doesn't like the "this" pointer.

Comment: It errors out in both IE 8 and Firefox 3.6 for me. In isolation the dialog works but when I pass that object to the  
            AddTaskDialog.dialog(AddTaskDialogOptions); something screws up with the "this" reference

Comment: I removed the Ajax part of it and it works. So, for some reason the "this' pointer gets messed up when it calls that obect from an Ajax request.

Comment: sorry, doesn´t matter what i do, i cannot reproduce your error. Are you sure you´re not doing somewhere something different wrong. Because if you get the error during the instantiation of the dialog, then the "this" keyword get´s not called, hence there is no reason to get the error, it must be somewhere else

Comment: I narrowed it down to the returned html from ajax request -  AddTaskDialog.html(AddTaskForm); If I put in a hardcoded string it works fine, otherwise it gives an error. I even took the returned result and hardcoded it all in there and it works...

Comment: I'm going to reopen this as a new question. Thanks for the help Luke

Comment: try AddTaskDialog.append(AddTaskForm)

Answer (score 0):

When we use jQuery we follow some basic rules.

```
var AddTaskDialog = $('<div></div>');
            AddTaskDialog.dialog(AddTaskDialogOptions);
            AddTaskDialog.html(AddTaskForm);
            AddTaskDialog.dialog('open');
```

u dont work like this. instead you do this.

```
var $dialog = $("<div></div>")
             .append(AddTaskForm)
             .dialog(AddTaskDialogOptions)
             .dialog("open");
```